# How to stop moving channels from changing during current bar

Tags: pine-script

In PineScript, I'm looking for a way to stop moving channels and/or moving averages from moving during the current bar. For example - if I'm using a Keltner Channel or ATR bands on 2 minute time frame, I do not want the channel/bands to move during the current 2 minutes. Whether its values are calculated from the open of the current bar or close of the previous bar, I need it to be stationary until the next bar when it recalculates and then moves. I've searched the manual and found barstate.isconfirmed, barstate.ishistory, etc., and I've tried plugging them into scripts but it doesn't change anything, which means that I'm not inputting it correctly. Any advice is much appreicated!

Comment: Please show us what you have done so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for replying - late yesterday I found a solution. I was able to add a forward offset to the indicators, which accomplished what I was looking to do rather easily (add offset = 1 to the plot). Thank you again for the reply!